# phpunit won't find the required files

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, phpunit

I am trying to test all my controllers in CakePHP 2.9.7 but getting an error after error. 
First is

`require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php, line 3]`

after this when I copy `Autoload.php` from `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObeject/Autoload.php to`

to

`/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/File/Iterator/`
as it's said in the error, it gives me another one

`require_once(): Failed opening required 'Text/Template/Autoload.php' (include_path='/shaufelcakephp/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in [/usr/local/lib/php/PHPUnit/File/Iterator/Autoload.php, line 3]`

So the quiestion is how could I do copy all these thigs in one step and from which place to which that should be done ?

`

Comment: You need to install PHPUnit. If you're going the "copy" route, this worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/28945419/929304

Comment: Make your life simpler and start using Composer as it will install the necessary files for you.